# Starting Neo4j Server failed: Component '' was successfully initialized, but failed to start

Tags: neo4j

I installed Neo4j community version yesterday on Windows 7.
Had no problems running and working with it.
Today I tried to start up the server again but received the following error message:

> Starting Neo4j Server failed: Component
>   'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@76c898cd' was
>   successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached
>   cause exception.

That's what I found in the message.log file in the database folder

```
    org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.LuceneLabelScanStore@7ad7c442' failed to initialize. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:489) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:72) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:106) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:530) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:117) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:331) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:59) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase$1.newGraphDatabase(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:44) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:110) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:203) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.desktop.runtime.DatabaseActions.start(DatabaseActions.java:71) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.desktop.ui.StartDatabaseActionListener$1.run(StartDatabaseActionListener.java:61) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_65]
Caused by: java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException: null
    at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.checkList(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.add(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.tryLock(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLock.obtain(NativeFSLockFactory.java:217) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.apache.lucene.store.Lock.obtain(Lock.java:72) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:1098) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.LuceneIndexWriter.<init>(LuceneIndexWriter.java:57) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.TrackingLuceneIndexWriter.<init>(TrackingLuceneIndexWriter.java:41) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.IndexWriterFactories$2.create(IndexWriterFactories.java:58) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.LuceneLabelScanStore.init(LuceneLabelScanStore.java:253) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:483) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
2015-08-27 00:34:39.895+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: --- STOPPING diagnostics START ---
2015-08-27 00:34:39.896+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.DiagnosticsManager]: --- STOPPING diagnostics END ---
2015-08-27 00:34:39.908+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: Shutdown started
2015-08-27 00:34:39.916+0000 ERROR [o.n.s.d.LifecycleManagingDatabase]: Failed to start database.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, \\zeus\home\085Home\waleczek\My Documents\Neo4j\default.graphdb
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:335) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.<init>(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:59) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase$1.newGraphDatabase(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:44) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:110) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:203) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.desktop.runtime.DatabaseActions.start(DatabaseActions.java:71) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.desktop.ui.StartDatabaseActionListener$1.run(StartDatabaseActionListener.java:61) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_65]
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager@59314fe9' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:513) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:331) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource@6c2a7bf9' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:513) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.state.DataSourceManager.start(DataSourceManager.java:117) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.LuceneLabelScanStore@7ad7c442' failed to initialize. Please see attached cause exception.
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:489) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:72) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:106) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.start(NeoStoreDataSource.java:530) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:507) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.nio.channels.OverlappingFileLockException: null
    at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.checkList(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at sun.nio.ch.SharedFileLockTable.add(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.tryLock(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.tryLock(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLock.obtain(NativeFSLockFactory.java:217) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.apache.lucene.store.Lock.obtain(Lock.java:72) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:1098) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.LuceneIndexWriter.<init>(LuceneIndexWriter.java:57) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.TrackingLuceneIndexWriter.<init>(TrackingLuceneIndexWriter.java:41) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.IndexWriterFactories$2.create(IndexWriterFactories.java:58) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.LuceneLabelScanStore.init(LuceneLabelScanStore.java:253) ~[neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:483) [neo4j-desktop-2.2.4.jar:2.2.4]
    ... 31 common frames omitted
2015-08-27 00:34:39.918+0000 INFO  [o.n.s.CommunityNeoServer]: Successfully shutdown Neo4j Server.
```

I deleted all database folders, since I only played around with the given Movie example. 
I also tried setting allow_store_upgrade=true
, both without success.

I did however restart my laptop today and windows installed some updates. Currently I am wondering if that could have caused the error.

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: Can you tell us of the "attached cause exception"?

Comment: Sorry, got the idea just now to have a look for a log file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move your database from remote location to local drive.

from `\\zeus\home\085Home\waleczek\My Documents\Neo4j\default.graphdb`

e.g. to `C:\some\directory\neo4j\default.graphdb`

And change location in configuration file accordingly.

Or map your remote as a network drive.
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/create-shortcut-map-network-drive#1TC=windows-7

Comment: I am trying to integrate Elasticsearch with Neo4j and I am having the same error. I tried your solution but it didn't work for me. I had to copy some jars to plugin folder to integrate Elasticsearch with Neo4j and when I do that I get this error, when I remove them the server starts without problems.